# Help understanding MVar example in Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency

I'm trying to understand the MVar example in the [GHC latest docs](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.4.0.0/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html) -

```
data SkipChan a = SkipChan (MVar (a, [MVar ()])) (MVar ())

newSkipChan :: IO (SkipChan a)
newSkipChan = do
     sem <- newEmptyMVar
     main <- newMVar (undefined, [sem])
     return (SkipChan main sem)

putSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> a -> IO ()
putSkipChan (SkipChan main _) v = do
     (_, sems) <- takeMVar main
     putMVar main (v, [])
     mapM_ (sem -> putMVar sem ()) sems

getSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> IO a
getSkipChan (SkipChan main sem) = do
     takeMVar sem
     (v, sems) <- takeMVar main
     putMVar main (v, sem:sems)
     return v

dupSkipChan :: SkipChan a -> IO (SkipChan a)
dupSkipChan (SkipChan main _) = do
     sem <- newEmptyMVar
     (v, sems) <- takeMVar main
     putMVar main (v, sem:sems)
     return (SkipChan main sem)
```

I understand most of the program but for two questions -

1. Are operations like `putSkipChan` atomic? It seems to avoid blocking on `putMVar` by first doing a `takeMVar`. But wouldn't that fail if something else calls `putMVar` after the `takeMVar` but before the `putMVar`? In such cases, it seems the program would block forever.
2. Why does `dupSkipChan` append `sem` to the list of semaphores in the `SkipChan`? Isn't that done by `getSkipChan`. It seems to me that calling `dupSkipChan` followed by `getSkipChan` (which seems to be what you *have* to do to have multiple readers) would cause a block when `putSkipChan` tries to wake up the same semaphore twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are correct, another thread could call `putMVar main` and mess up `putSkipChan`.  But the module creating the above code would not export the `SkipChan` constructor so such a rogue operation would be impossible.
2. `dupSkipChan` makes a *new* `emptyMVar` called `sem` and adds that to the list in main.  It does not add the pre-existing one that was created in `newSkipChan`.  Thus there is no block.

To explain more to other readers of this question and comment: The idea is that there may be multiple reader threads.  Initially `SkipChan main sem1` is the only such reader.  `dupSkipChan` makes a `SkipChan main sem2`.  If there are thousands of readers then you would not want to notify all of them of a new value in `putSkipChan`, thus the design is that `getSkipChan` puts its sem into the list in main.  Initializing `SkipChan` as done in `newSkipChan` and `dupSkipChan` also includes putting the new empty `sem` into the list in main.

The above initialization and design means that the first `getSkipChan` obtains the most recent past value to have been written (or block for the first value to arrive). Future `getSkipChan` on that `SkipChan` will always get a newer value than any gotten before, and these will not block if that value is already available.